# How to separate URL string into parts using Regex

Tags: php, regex, url

I have following URL string

```
/category/category1/2010/12/10/id
```

I need to separate string into parts. I'm trying this pattern

```
(?:(.*))?(?:(?:\/)?([0-9]{4}))?(?:(?:\/)?([0-9]{1,2}))?(?:(?:\/)?([0-9]{1,2}))?(?:(.*))?
```

but it doesn't work properly

if URL is like this `/category/category1/`, I need the following vars

```
path = '/category/category1/';
year = '';
month = '';
day = '';
id ='';
```

if URL is like this `/category/category1/2010`, I need the following vars

```
path = '/category/category1/2010';
year = '2010';
month = '';
day = '';
id ='';
```

if URL is like this `/category/category1/2010/12/`, I need the following vars

```
path = '/category/category1/2010/12';
year = '2010';
month = '12';
day = '';
id ='';
```

if URL is like this `/category/category1/2010/12/10`, I need the following vars

```
path = '/category/category1/2010/12/10';
year = '2010';
month = '12';
day = '10';
id ='';
```

if URL is like this `/category/category1/2010/12/10/id`, I need the following vars

```
path = '/category/category1/2010/12/10/id';
year = '2010';
month = '12';
day = '10';
id ='id';
```

Is it possible to make this with `preg_match` and regex?

Comment: what if someone calls `/category/category1/id` or any other combination you didnt list? Why not just use plain old query strings instead, e.g. `?category=1&d=2010-12-10&id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use preg_match. The following regex is tested with all examples in the question:

```
$regex = '/^(\\/[^\\/]+\\/[^\\/]+\\/)\\/?([0-9]{4})?\\/?([0-9]{2})?\\/?([0-9]{2})?\\/?(.*)$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $url, $match))
    print_r($match);
else
    die('No match.');
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply `explode('/', $url);`

Now you've got an array of the URL pieces. If you're also after validation you can now validate each piece (that exists) individually, and the whole thing will be a lot clearer.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, explode will separate and category/category1/category2 and this going to break my script i think

Comment: @Alex: In what way would it break your script?

Comment: the problem i think is coming from if i have, for example category 1234 the url will look like /1234/2001 when i check for there is year i will detect year 2001 but when i trying to access to category /1234 the script perhaps trying to get year 1234

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
function findInfo ($path) {
    return array_slice(explode('/', trim($path, '/')), 2);
}

$path = "/category/category1/2010/12/10/id";
list($year, $month, $day, $id) = findInfo($path);

var_dump($path, $year, $month, $day, $id);

$path = "/category/category1/";
list($year, $month, $day, $id) = findInfo($path);

var_dump($path, $year, $month, $day, $id);

$path = "/category/category1/2010/";
list($year, $month, $day, $id) = findInfo($path);

var_dump($path, $year, $month, $day, $id);

$path = "/category/category1/2010/12";
list($year, $month, $day, $id) = findInfo($path);

var_dump($path, $year, $month, $day, $id);

$path = "/category/category1/2010/12/10";
list($year, $month, $day, $id) = findInfo($path);

var_dump($path, $year, $month, $day, $id);
```

Output:

```
string(33) "/category/category1/2010/12/10/id"
string(4) "2010"
string(2) "12"
string(2) "10"
string(2) "id"
string(20) "/category/category1/"
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
string(25) "/category/category1/2010/"
string(4) "2010"
NULL
NULL
NULL
string(27) "/category/category1/2010/12"
string(4) "2010"
string(2) "12"
NULL
NULL
string(30) "/category/category1/2010/12/10"
string(4) "2010"
string(2) "12"
string(2) "10"
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

simple list() function

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://example.com/category/category1/2010/12/10/id';
$url = str_ireplace('http://example.com/','',$url);
/*
category/category1/2010/12/10/id
=
//type/cat/year/month/day/id
using list()
*/
list($type,$cat,$year, $month, $day,$id) = explode('/',$url); 

echo $id.':'.$day.'-'.$month.'-'.$year;

?>
```